# Access folder icon properties

Tags: windows, resize, icons, directory, powerbuilder

In windows explorer we can see folders or different files. The icons of these can be reset by setting it different options like Tiles/List/Medium Icons/Extra Large Icons etc (accessible via a button on below the search bar in Windows 7)
I use CurrentViewMode() API to access these properties where I cannot see/access Extra Large Icons or Large Icons. Is there any other API which would cater to these needs or any other way how I can set these properties through powerbuilder code?

Comment: I'm not clear, are you trying to simulate windows explorer in a powerbuilder application? Or are you trying to change the user explorer settings from PB, if so I suspect that would be via registry changes using RegistrySet / RegistryGet need clarification...

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to simulate windows explorer in powerbuilder application.

Comment: Oh, I see. You might want to look at a project called PowerToTheBuilder.com or something. I think he is doing some fancy UI stuff like what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

I can use the **IconSize** property to store the current icon sizes. I store this value & reset it when user opens the application again.

Ex: `oleControl.Object.Document.IconSize`

How I found this?
It should have been simple as the property name says it. However, I found it from the registry settings, where there is a registry entry for IconSize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ListView control to do what you are talking about. When using it you can assign small picture, large picture, etc. for changing the display mode.

Comment: I have tried this out. One can set only two sizes - 16 pixels or 32 pixels. However, I want to be able to set any size.